# Which places have a majority of vegetarians?

Tags: vegetarian-diet, statistics

It is often heard that vegetarian movements are on the rise recently. Is there any place or country in the world, where the vegetarians are in the majority at present?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean >50% of the population in an area by *majority*, the answer is **no, there are no countries where this is true**.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism_by_country), the country with the highest amount of vegetarians is **India**, with a (rather staggering) 29%–40% of vegetarians. That's approximately **361 million people**, which is hard to visualise, I'd say.

[This article](https://www.scoopwhoop.com/This-Survey-Found-Out-How-Many-Indians-Are-NonVegetarians-And-Which-State-Is-The-Least-Vegetarian/#.oe4tnh51u) claims that the Rajasthan state of India is the 'most vegetarian', with approximately 75% of the population being counted as vegetarian. However, being a state of India and not a country, it doesn't change the fact that no whole countries are majority-vegetarian.

---

If you're interested in the other side—areas with the *least* vegetarians—Wikipedia states that only between 0.5%–4% of Spaniards are vegetarian. That's about 1.8 million people in Spain who are vegetarian, according to the estimates used by Wikipedia.